# FBSession __destroy_helper_block_ crash

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am getting a fairly constant stream of facebook related crashes in an app with 150k users. 2-3% of users who try to sync to facebook seem to be getting this crash. It looks like maybe the block is released 2x?, some key info from the crash report is posted below. Any ideas where to approach this from since its in the facebook SDK's code?

```
__destroy_helper_block_
in FBSession.m, line 1153

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xc
Crashed Thread:  0
```

> ```
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b43fb26 _objc_msgSend + 6
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b44fb0b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 175
> 2   Memoir                              0x0010719b __destroy_helper_block_ (FBSession.m:1153)
> 3   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x3b969ac5 __Block_release + 217
> 4   libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x3b969ac5 __Block_release + 217
> 5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b927d67 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
> 6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b92e7c1 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 269
> 7   CoreFoundation                      0x31038821 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
> 8   CoreFoundation                      0x310370f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1301
> 9   CoreFoundation                      0x30fa1ce7 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
> 10  CoreFoundation                      0x30fa1acb _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
> 11  GraphicsServices                    0x35cc2283 _GSEventRunModal + 139
> 12  UIKit                               0x33843a41 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
> 13  Memoir                              0x00096353 main (main.m:20)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an internal bug in the Facebook SDK. An update eventually fixed this.